# Where are Chromium extensions stored on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I'm using the Google [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en) app as a Chromium extension. My platform is Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) with the LXDE desktop. I need to change some basic configuration such as the indentation size but cannot find where the configuration files are stored.

Where are Chromium extensions stored on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: See answer on askubutu [Where are chromium extensions located?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26782) -- which is the first result when you google "Where are Chromium extensions stored on Ubuntu Linux?" :/

Comment: For some reason I didn't find that answer when I searched Google. Perhaps my search string was slightly different to yours. Thanks for the link by the way, can you post as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where are Chromium extensions stored on Ubuntu Linux?

> Extensions are stored at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions`.
>   Here's an example featuring the amazing
>   [adblock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom):
>
> ```
> jake@daedalus:~$ cd .config/chromium/Default/Extensions/
> jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions$ ls
> gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/  jggheggpdocamneaacmfoipeehedigia/
> jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions$ cd gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/2.3.1_0/
> jake@daedalus:~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/2.3.1_0$ ls
> adblock.js        background.html  blacklisting/         button/     functions.js  img/        jquery/    manifest.json  pages/  whitelister.js
> adblock_start.js  blacklister.js   broadcast_channel.js  filtering/  Icon.png      Info.plist  _locales/  options/       port.js
> ```
>
> To see it in your file browser, make sure you can see hidden files
>   (View > Show Hidden Files). Or, do like Gaurav says and type in the
>   path after pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

[image]

Source [Where are chromium extensions located?](https://askubuntu.com/a/26785/376050) on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) by [djeikyb](https://askubuntu.com/users/8515/djeikyb)